# Thread Safe Timed Events

Tags: c#, multithreading, service, timer

I asked a question earlier on this thread [Timed events overlapping during execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38656614/timed-events-overlapping-during-execution/38675890#38675890) 
The answer I got didnt really work out as I expected. I modified it a little bit based on the msdn https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked(v=vs.110).aspx  article and it worked. Or so I think.
Here is my modified code

```
 public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{

    private Timer timer1 = null;
    private long isTaskRunning = 0;

    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        timer1 = new Timer();
        this.timer1.Interval = 1000;
        this.timer1.Elapsed += new  System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        Library.WriteErrorLog("service has started");
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
     Console.WriteLine("Acquiring Lock");
        try
        {

        if (Interlocked.Exchange(ref isTaskRunning, 1)==1)
        {
         Console.WriteLine("Lock Denied");
         return;
        }

        else
        { 
         Console.WriteLine("Lock Acquired");
         //retrieve data from database
        //read rows

        //Loop through rows
        //send values through network
        //receive response and update db
         Interlocked.Exchange(ref isTaskRunning, 0);
        }

       }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Library.WriteErrorLog(ex);
        }

    }
}

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        timer1.Enabled = false;
        Library.WriteErrorLog("service has stopped");
    }
}
```

My question now is, is this code Thread-safe?
And is there any possibility that this code might crash. 
The code is supposed to run on Virtual Private Server and is a part of business critical system. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first place, you want [Interlocked.CompareExchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yss0xc74(v=vs.110).aspx) there, rather than `Interlocked.Exchange`. If you use `Interlocked.Exchange`, your code will allow reentrancy every other time. And could fail to allow the code to run when it should.

I don't know if you intended this, but if your processing throws an exception then the `isTaskRunning` is never reset to 0.

You can do the same thing a lot easier with a [Monitor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
private object _timerLock = new object();

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Acquiring Lock");
    if (!Monitor.TryEnter(_timerLock))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Lock Denied");
        return;
    }

    try
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Lock Acquired");
        //retrieve data from database
        //read rows

        //Loop through rows
        //send values through network
        //receive response and update db
        Monitor.Exit(_timerLock);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Library.WriteErrorLog(ex);
    }
}
```

Again, this will continue to hold the lock if an exception is thrown. You could move the `Monitor.Exit` into a `finally` block, but that raises other issues. See Eric Lippert's [Locks and exceptions do not mix](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/03/06/locks-and-exceptions-do-not-mix/). Using an `Interlocked.CompareExchange` to do the locking doesn't change the fundamental problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Jim Mischel. I feel as if I just opened a pandora's box though. I want to ask, if I stop and restart the timer in the `ElaspsedEvent` handler, will this work? As mentioned in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38656614/timed-events-overlapping-during-execution/38675890?noredirect=1#comment64961100_38675890

`

Comment: @elfico: Yes, stopping and re-starting the timer is a good way to do things. That eliminates the lock problems, and prevents re-entrance. Also, be careful with `System.Timers.Timer`: it swallows exceptions. See http://blog.mischel.com/2011/05/19/swallowing-exceptions-is-hiding-bugs/ for more detail.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jim Mischel. I just want to ask if `System.Threading.Timer` will be a better option. I have read a lot of post on Stackoverflow saying the `System.Threading.Timer` is not thread-safe.

Comment: @elfico: `System.Timers.Timer` is a component wrapper around `System.Threading.Timer`. The wrapper adds the event interface, and also a `SynchronizingObject` member that lets you automatically synchronize with the UI thread. You can do that yourself with `System.Threading.Timer` by calling `Dispatch` or `Invoke` to synchronize. Both timers are "thread safe." Just remember that the callback for `System.Threading.Timer` executes on a separate thread. The `Elapsed` event for `System.Timers.Timer` normally executes on a separate thread, but *can be made* to execute on the UI thread.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. I tried starting and stopping the timers and it didnt work. I used the `Monitor.TryEnter` and it worked very well. But I once a while, I get `A transport-level error has occurred when sending the request to the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)`  error and the lock gets hold for a long time. And when it is released, it works a while and then gets held again. Please how best can I handle this.

Answer (score 1):

After reading Jim Mischel's answer and reading the linked post ([Locks and exceptions do not mix](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/03/06/locks-and-exceptions-do-not-mix/)), I put together a hypothetical model of how this might work.

I'd recommend that the class setting the timer and handling its events be separate from the one that invokes whatever behavior happens. Going a step further, perhaps the `ComponentUsed` class (didn't think too hard about that name) should itself just be a wrapper for the class that invokes some actual behavior.

That keeps responsibilities separate. One class is responsible for doing something when a timer elapses, not knowing about locks and failed states. This is important in case that behavior must be replicated somewhere other than that timer event.

The responsibility of locking, handling exceptions, and determining/knowing whether the component is in a failed state is separate.

In this case if the component fails and enters a failed state where subsequent calls shouldn't be processed, it raises an `EnteredFailedState` event. `RunsOnTimer` can respond to this by stopping its timer and doing whatever else it must do to respond. If it's a Windows service it might log the exception and shut down.

But whether the timer continues to elapse or not, the inner component is managing responsibility for its own failed state. It knows that it should not continue to handle requests.

This is just conceptual, but I might build on this if I have such a scenario where I have to both lock and handle exceptions. It doesn't matter much if the process can safely continue even if the process within the lock throws an exception.

```
public class RunsOnTimer
{
    private readonly Timer _timer = new Timer(1000);
    private readonly ComponentUsed _component = new ComponentUsed();

    public RunsOnTimer()
    {
        _component.EnteredFailedState += Component_EnteredFailedState;
        _timer.Elapsed += _timer_Elapsed;
    }

    private void Component_EnteredFailedState(ComponentUsed sender, EnteredFailedStateEventArgs e)
    {
        _timer.Stop();
    }

    private void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        _component.DoSomething();
    }
}

// Some component containing the actual behavior being invoked
// when the timer elapses.

public class ComponentUsed
{
    private readonly object _doingSomethingLock = new object();
    private bool _failedState;

    public event EnteredFailedStateEventHandler EnteredFailedState;
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        if (_failedState) return; //Perhaps throw an exception.
        if (!Monitor.TryEnter(_doingSomethingLock)) return;
        try
        {
            // Do whatever the component does
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Is the exception fatal? Should we stop executing this?
            EnterFailedState(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            Monitor.Exit(_doingSomethingLock);
        }
    }

    private void EnterFailedState(Exception ex)
    {
        _failedState = true;
        if (EnteredFailedState != null) EnteredFailedState(this, new EnteredFailedStateEventArgs(ex));
    }
}
```